# How to initialize char pointer array, to avoid garbage values?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, garbage

I am having an issue where some global char pointer arrays that I am trying to initialize become full of garbage data after the function that I initialized them in goes out of scope.

```
char *dept_vals[255];
char *num_vals[255];
char *day_vals[255];
char *bldg_vals[255];
char *instr_vals[255];
int start_vals[255];
int end_vals[255];
int sect_vals[255];
int room_vals[255];

int idx;

static int callback(void *NotUsed, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName)
{
    int i = 0;
    while(i < argc)
    {
        dept_vals[idx] = argv[i++];
        num_vals[idx] = argv[i++];
        start_vals[idx] = atoi(argv[i++]);
        end_vals[idx] = atoi(argv[i++]);
        day_vals[idx] = argv[i++];
        sect_vals[idx] = atoi(argv[i++]);
        bldg_vals[idx] = argv[i++];
        room_vals[idx] = atoi(argv[i++]);
        instr_vals[idx] = argv[i++];

        idx++;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I print the values in a different function, the contents are incorrect. However, the values in the integer arrays that I initialized in the same function have the right values. I suspect that the way I am initializing the char pointer arrays is causing unexpected behavior, but I'm not completely sure what is the correct way to initialize them in this situation.

Comment: You put this condition `i < argc` but you never check it again inside the loop, though you are incrementing the `i` 9 times, did you check that `argc % 9 == 0`?

Comment: are you including `stdlib.h` yesterday I saw a case where that was the problem.

Comment: I understand you to mean that the integer values are correct but the `char*` results are not. Show us the way you are printing the `char*` results.

Comment: '=' only copies the pointers. If you want the actual strings, you'll have to allocate space for them with malloc(), and strcpy() them into it.

Comment: Yes, I did check and argc % 9 == 0. I actually forgot to explicitly include stdlib.h, but I think it must have been included in another one of my header files because atoi works fine. Explicitly including it did not change anything.

Comment: What @LeeDanielCrocker said. Alternatively, you can just keep the pointers, but you must make sure that the memory chunks pointed to are still in scope and valid when you print them.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker the arrays are char pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code like

```
dept_vals[idx] = argv[i++];
```

copies the *address* of argv[i] into dept_vals[idx], but as you point out, that goes out of scope when you return. You want to copy the actual string:

```
dept_vals[idx] = malloc(strlen(argv[i]) + 1);
strcpy(dept_vals[idx], argv[i]);
++i;
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing how you call the function, it just guessing.

If you use gcc try to replace:

```
... = argv[i++];
```

with

```
... = argv[i] ?strdup(argv[i]) :NULL; ++i;
```

and compile using with the options `-D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED`.

[`strdup()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html) duplicates the "string" being passed.